# Service not defined

Tags: plugin-development, services

I'm trying to build my first plugin using a service but i can't seem to get it to work.

The file is named CampaignReports_CampaignMonitorService.php and it's in the services folder of my plugin.

This is the code of the service:

```
class CampaignReports_CampaignMonitorService extends BaseApplicationComponent
{

    public function __construct()
    {        

    }

    public function getSettings()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I'm calling the service as follow:

```
craft()->campaignReports_CampaignMonitor->getSettings();
```

This causes an internal server error with the following message:

```
Internal Server Error

Property "Craft\WebApp.campaignReports_CampaignMonitor" is not defined.
```

Any idea what i'm doing wrong? Probably some naming convention I haven't followed exactly but I just don't find it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like a casing issue to me. You should be calling:

```
craft()->campaignReports_campaignMonitor->getSettings();
```

Comment: No problem! Happy to help :)